# ftp_put(): Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/xxx.txt"

Tags: php, ftp

I am working on to upload the file to FTP using PHP FTP. while putting the file to the server, its throw error.

what I did:

```
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect(SAP_SERVER_HOST, SAP_SERVER_PORT, 60);
    if (!ftp_login($ftp_conn, SAP_SERVER_USER, SAP_SERVER_PASSWORD)) {
        echo 'not connected<br/>';
    } else {
        $localfile = '/abc/txt/15375127769260.txt';
        $serverfile = '/folder/15375127769260.txt';
        // echo ftp_pwd($ftp_conn);
        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $serverfile, $localfile, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "Successfully uploaded $localfile.";
        } else {
            echo "Error uploading $localfile.";
        }
        // close connection
        ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    }
```

Suggest Me, what I miss in this code.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this:
my file was sent correctly after adding `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);`

*Note that it must be added after ftp_login().*

[ftp-pasv on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php)

Answer (score 0):

are you using right folders and ports ?

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect(SAP_SERVER_HOST, SAP_SERVER_PORT, 60);
```

it should be port `21`
and in local file you must get get the realpath of the file whit `realpath()` function
and for remote server the path is based on ftp base folder

Take a look of realpath http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.realpath.php

Comment: we are user custom port for this ftp connection, not using 21 and i am using full path of the local and remote , still same issue

Comment: the ftp server needs explicit ssl or tls connection?

Comment: I think, its plain FTP, because while connect this ftp using file zilla, its throw `Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.` this message